# Line drawing using Applet is all messed up now

Tags: java, awt

We recently started using Applet and doing stuff with it, so the last class was on drawing lines. So after writing a successful code i changed a line of code for some reason unbeknownst to me and now it does not draw a line, rather draws a weird ray sort of. 
Here is the code so any help would be appreciated.

```
import java.applet.Applet;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.event.MouseAdapter;
import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;
import java.awt.event.MouseMotionAdapter;

public class SimplePaint extends Applet {
    private int lastx;
    private int lasty;
    @Override
    public void init() {
        this.setForeground(Color.BLUE);
        this.addMouseListener(new PositionRecorder());
        this.addMouseMotionListener(new LineDrawer());
    }
    public int getLastx() {
        return lastx;
    }
    public void setLastx(int lastx) {
        this.lastx = lastx;
    }
    public int getLasty() {
        return lasty;
    }
    public void setLasty(int lasty) {
        this.lasty = lasty;
    }
    private class PositionRecorder extends MouseAdapter{
        public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e) {
            setLastx(e.getX());
            setLasty(e.getY());

        }
    }
    private class LineDrawer extends MouseMotionAdapter{
        public void mouseDragged(MouseEvent e) {
            int x=e.getX();
            int y=e.getY();
            Graphics g;
            g=getGraphics();
            g.drawLine(lastx, lasty, x, y);

        }

    }
}
```

I distinctively remember messing with this part of code if that helps

```
private class PositionRecorder extends MouseAdapter{
   public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e) {
     setLastx(e.getX());
     setLasty(e.getY());
```

Comment: 1. Applets are dead, time to move on, they are no longer support and are a general waste of your time (and no, they are not easy to learn). 2. Don't use `getGraphics()`, this is not how custom painting is ever done. Instead, take a look at [Painting in AWT and Swing](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/painting-140037.html) to get a better understanding of how painting actually works.

Comment: 3. Also, I would highly recommend that you do a google search for something like [painting in java awt](https://www.google.com.au/search?safe=off&client=safari&rls=en&dcr=0&ei=PW2YWpTVDMWX8wXZrqWACw&q=painting+in+java+awt&oq=painting+in+java+awt&gs_l=psy-ab.3..0i71k1l8.67598.67958.0.68054.5.4.0.0.0.0.0.0..0.0....0...1c.1.64.psy-ab..5.0.0....0.WgvvQ8t_PNs) as SO is not a replacement for decent tutorials or the JavaDocs

Comment: @MadProgrammer  This will come on my test though, and I doubt they will accept "Applets are dead" as an answer

Comment: Then it's time to find a better teacher - Applets are officially deprecated, the applet plugin has been discontinued and all modern browsers either actively disable it or don't support it. BUT - reading through the link in the first comment relates to both AWT and Swing APIs and will give you a better understanding into how painting actually works and how you can work with it

Comment: @MadProgrammer I even more doubt that the college will appreciate me coming to them and saying yeah the teacher is shit and we arent learning anything. Before you say anything else, this is literally the most computer oriented college in my country, so all I want to know is can you help me with the code I posted or if you cant, thanks anyway man.

Comment: Go read [Painting in AWT and Swing](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/painting-140037.html) - it will help answer your question. Do a google search on ["painting in java awt"](https://www.google.com.au/search?safe=off&client=safari&rls=en&dcr=0&ei=PW2YWpTVDMWX8wXZrqWACw&q=painting+in+java+awt&oq=painting+in+java+awt&gs_l=psy-ab.3..0i71k1l8.67598.67958.0.68054.5.4.0.0.0.0.0.0..0.0....0...1c.1.64.psy-ab..5.0.0....0.WgvvQ8t_PNs) - it will provide additional information and examples. *" can you help me with the code"* - The answer is, I shouldn't have to. Your question isn't that unique

Comment: @MadProgrammer Sorry,posted cause I couldnt find anything that was exactly my problem, thanks anyway man.

Comment: [Might be a good place to start](http://www.dgp.toronto.edu/~mjmcguff/learn/java/08-painting/), [might also help](https://www.javatpoint.com/java-applet) - as I stated, you should never use `getGraphics` - this is not how custom painting works

Answer (score 2):

Painting in AWT is a well documented process.  You should start by reading through:

- [Painting in AWT and Swing](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/painting-140037.html), in particular, I suggest you read the section on [The Paint Method](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/painting-140037.html#callback)
- [A Closer Look at the Paint Mechanism](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/painting/closer.html)

Quoted from "A Closer Look at the Paint Mechanism"

> the paint method (defined by java.awt.Component.) This method will be executed by the painting subsystem whenever you component needs to be rendered.

In AWT, painting is destructive, it is expected that any time `paint` is called, that you will completely repaint the component state.  This raises a number of issue which you will need to solve.

For anything you need to paint, you need a reliable way to store those states and reapply them when `paint` is called.  In you case, something as simple as an `ArrayList` would be suitable, but you could also use a `BufferedImage` as a backing buffer and draw the committed drawing elements to it.

The benefit of the first approach is to provides the ability to undo changes, but in terms of painting, isn't as fast as simply painting an image.

A more clever approach would be to use both.  Maintaining the draw states in a `ArrayList`, rendering each one as it's committed to the `BufferedImage` and when you want to perform an undo, start with a new `BufferedImage` and paint all the states up to the point you don't need...but that's all beyond the scope of the question

```
import java.applet.Applet;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Point;
import java.awt.event.MouseAdapter;
import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;
import java.awt.event.MouseMotionAdapter;

public class SimplePaint extends Applet {

    private Point clickPoint;
    private Point dragPoint;

    @Override
    public void init() {
        this.setForeground(Color.BLUE);
        this.addMouseListener(new PositionRecorder());
        this.addMouseMotionListener(new LineDrawer());
    }

    @Override
    public void paint(Graphics g) {
        super.paint(g);
        if (clickPoint != null && dragPoint != null) {
            g.drawLine(clickPoint.x, clickPoint.y, dragPoint.x, dragPoint.y);
        }
    }

    private class PositionRecorder extends MouseAdapter {

        public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e) {
            clickPoint = e.getPoint();
        }

        @Override
        public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent e) {
            // This is where I'd reset the clickPoint and dragPoint
            // to null and apply the line to some structure which can
            // redraw it in the `paint` method, maybe something like
            // a ArrayList
            // Alternativly, you could render the result to a BufferedImage
            // and paint that inside the paint method
        }
    }

    private class LineDrawer extends MouseMotionAdapter {

        public void mouseDragged(MouseEvent e) {
            dragPoint = e.getPoint();
            repaint();
        }

    }
}
```